# Likert Item phrasing for postive and negative statements

Tags: likert

To avoid some confusion, I am not referring to the scale, but the statement itself. Is there a rule to phrase the statements to capture the same conceptual meaning. For example:

Positive: "The tool was easy to use".

Negative: "The tool was difficult to use".

Comment: It is difficult to guess what you are asking.  "The same conceptual meaning" as *what*? Are you asking how to rephrase questions in a way that is unlikely to change the responses to them?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is create several likert items with the same meaning to gauge student's attitude towards tablets to see if it was effective. I want to create a summed score of the items. I want to phrase the items to reduce acquiescence, the bias of agreeing with the statement without thinking about it. I'm trying to do this by phrasing the items in a negative manner. Hope that make sense.

Comment: There were some suggestion to phrase the items in a way such as "Do you think a tablet is better than a computer" which I think does not capture if a tablet was effective, and I think interferes with the mean the summed score.

Comment: OK, thank you. But what exactly is your question, then?